# CountChars array string loop function letter occurrence

Tags: c, function, loops, char, letter

I'm trying to advance my skills in c,  I'm a bit confused when it comes to understand different ways to calculate the occurrence of letters in a string with a **function**, would be great to receive different views on how I could improve the code or a new way to count how many times a letter occur in a string with a function.

Any advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int countingCharacters(char *message, int size, char charToBeCounted);


int main() {

    char arrMess[13] = { "hejsanSvejsan" };
    char charsToBeCounted = 'a';

    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {

        printf("%c, %d:\n", charsToBeCounted, countingCharacters(arrMess, 13, charsToBeCounted));
        charsToBeCounted++;

    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int countingCharacters(char *message, int size, char charToBeCounted) {

    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < size)
    {
        if (message[i] == charToBeCounted)
            counter++;
        i++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be the right place to ask this question.

Comment: `charsToBeCounted` is unnecessary, I think it would be clearer and faster although negligibly so to simply make `i` a char. Also aside from not leaving room for a nul terminator, hard coding the size will make the code harder to change. I'm guessing the question is mostly asking, is there a faster way to count the amount of times a char occurs, unfortunately in terms of complexity, there's not. `int i = 'a'; i <= 'z';` is good, but to be pedantic, I don't think the decimal values of 'a' to 'z' have to be in order and contiguous, the only really solution is to use an array or library.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is counting every letter (a to z) in the string, you could do it one pass and use an array to track how many there are of each. Something along the lines of:

```
void countingCharacters(char *message, unsigned int count[]) {
    while(*message) {
        if(isalpha(*message)) {
            count[tolower(*message)-'a']++;
        }
        message++;
    }
}

int main() {

    char arrMess[] = { "hejsanSvejsan" };
    char i;
    unsigned int count[26] = { 0 };

    countingCharacters(arrMess,count);
    for(i='a';i<='z';i++) {
        printf("%c, %d:\n", i, count[i-'a']);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I removed the hard coding of the size of `arrMess`, by the way, because it was wrong. Your string was 13 characters long which would be too big to fit into a char array of size 13 as you need 1 extra to store the `'\0'` at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can omitted `size` and check for '\0' at the end of the string.

```
int countingCharacters(char *message, char charToBeCounted) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (message != '\0')
    {
        if (*message == charToBeCounted)
            counter++;
        message++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```